# Java Insert on update request

Tags: java, mysql

In my application, I make an UPDATE request but it adds a new entry on the the table.

There is the request:

```
UPDATE t_utilisateurs SET txt_courriel = ?, char_password = ?, txt_nom_utilisateur = ?, txt_prenom_utilisateur = ?, txt_adresse = ?, txt_ville = ?, txt_code_postal = ?, bigint_telephone = ?, bigint_cellulaire = ?, date_debut = ?, date_fin = ?, int_acces = ?, fk_departement = ? WHERE pk_utilisateur = ?
```

I don't understand why it creates a new entry instead it is supposed to update the entry selected.

Comment: Is it performing an upsert? Update if exists insert if it doesn't...

Comment: Show your code where you use the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the value in the where-clause (pk_utilisateur) is not present in the database and the update defaults to an insert for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention, but I finally fin the error. I made a stupid error when I declare my form object and I didn't see it :(

```
//Bugged
Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur.creerUtilisateur( request );

// Fixed
Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
```